Getting error Module not found in module-info.java with Maven
I am getting module not found when compiling with maven. This is a simple project for testing some concepts, it can be found here on Github. Here are the errors:
/home/TestQuerydsl/src/main/java/module-info.java:2: error: module not found: javafx.controls
    requires javafx.controls;
                   ^
/home/TestQuerydsl/src/main/java/module-info.java:3: error: module not found: javafx.fxml
    requires javafx.fxml;
                   ^
/home/TestQuerydsl/src/main/java/module-info.java:4: error: module not found: java.persistence
    requires java.persistence;

Full module-info.java
module com.intelidia.testquerydsl {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.persistence;


    opens com.intelidia.testquerydsl to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.intelidia.testquerydsl;
}

Full pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.intelidia.testquerydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestQuerydsl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TestQuerydsl</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.10.0</junit.version>
        <querydsl.version>5.1.0</querydsl.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>








        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>






            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>
                                com.intelidia.testquerydsl.testquerydsl/com.intelidia.testquerydsl.testquerydsl.HelloApplication
                            </mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


Does this help: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/maven ? It appears you do not have the JavaFX JAR files. Can you verify?

@Abra, I have already put the declarations in maven, do I still need the jar files, i'm not an expert in maven but is it not suppose to replace the manual addition of jars and manage these dependencies?

@Slaw, thanks for giving this a try, i'm in the same situation as you, i'll try to look into this module-info.java

@Slaw, i've noticed that removing apt-maven-plugin from pom.xml solves the issue, but i need this plugin

If you remove the plugin, the Q classes from Querydsl are not generated. In the link you shared, it says this "And now, configure the Maven APT plugin:"...

Consider if your app needs to be modular. If not, you could delete the module-info and JavaFX dependencies and use a JDK that includes JavaFX like some Azul or Liberica distributions.

@jewelsea, if I delete module-info, it is obligatory that I use a JDK that already includes JavaFX?

"if I delete module-info, it is obligatory that I use a JDK that already includes JavaFX?" -> No, you can follow the getting started instructions for non-modular JavaFX apps on the OpenJDK which are provided at openjfx.io if you don't want to use a JDK that includes JavaFX.

Note the answer below assumes you want or need your project to be modular. If that's not the case, then the easiest solution is to just delete your module-info.java file. Plus, some of your dependencies are non-modular. Having a dependency on automatic modules negates many of the benefits of modular code (e.g., jlink cannot work with automatic modules). Also see jewelsea's comment about possibly using JDKs that include JavaFX.
Whether you keep your code modular or not, I still suggest removing apt-maven-plugin and moving the annotation processor configuration to maven-compiler-plugin  instead.

Those "module not found" errors are emitted by the com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin plugin. That plugin's repository was archived in 2021 and the latest release on Maven Central says it was published 9 years ago in 2015 (note Java 9 was released in 2017). I'm not sure why the querydsl-jpa documentation still says to apply it. Maybe someone more familiar with Querydsl can provide some clarification, because removing that plugin and configuring the annotation processor in the maven-compiler-plugin plugin instead seems to work just as well:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>11</source>
        <target>11</target>
        <annotationProcessors>
            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
        </annotationProcessors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

Or at least, that solves the "module not found" errors. But now it fails with:
l error compiling: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Entity: javax.persistence.Entity

From what I can tell, this error is caused by the following:

When compiling a module, annotation processors picked up from the class-path or processor-path cannot find classes on the module-path (don't know if this is documented anywhere). Your project has a module-info.java file, so you are compiling a module.

Maven is placing the javax.persistence-api dependency on module-path only.

The querydsl-apt dependency does not have a transitive dependency on javax.persistence-api.


It looks like one way to fix this is to explicitly set the processor-path:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>11</source>
        <target>11</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
        <annotationProcessors>
            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
        </annotationProcessors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

We're getting closer, but now this fails with:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project TestQuerydsl: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/koles/Desktop/TestQueryDSL/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/intelidia/testquerydsl/testquerydsl/models/QUser.java:[3,32] package com.querydsl.core.types is not visible
[ERROR]   (package com.querydsl.core.types is declared in the unnamed module, but module com.intelidia.testquerydsl does not read it)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/koles/Desktop/TestQueryDSL/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/intelidia/testquerydsl/testquerydsl/models/QUser.java:[5,31] package com.querydsl.core.types.dsl is not visible
[ERROR]   (package com.querydsl.core.types.dsl is declared in the unnamed module, but module com.intelidia.testquerydsl does not read it)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/koles/Desktop/TestQueryDSL/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/intelidia/testquerydsl/testquerydsl/models/QUser.java:[7,25] package com.querydsl.core.types is not visible
[ERROR]   (package com.querydsl.core.types is declared in the unnamed module, but module com.intelidia.testquerydsl does not read it)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/koles/Desktop/TestQueryDSL/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/intelidia/testquerydsl/testquerydsl/models/QUser.java:[8,24] package javax.annotation.processing is not visible
[ERROR]   (package javax.annotation.processing is declared in module java.compiler, but module com.intelidia.testquerydsl does not read it)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/koles/Desktop/TestQueryDSL/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/intelidia/testquerydsl/testquerydsl/models/QUser.java:[9,25] package com.querydsl.core.types is not visible
[ERROR]   (package com.querydsl.core.types is declared in the unnamed module, but module com.intelidia.testquerydsl does not read it)

The fix for that is to modify your module-info.java file to add the following:
requires static java.compiler;
requires com.querydsl.core;

Those are necessary because the generated code is being compiled into your module.

The generated code includes a javax.annotation.processing.Generated annotation. That annotation comes from the java.compiler module. But the annotation is only required at compile-time, hence the use of requires static instead of requires.

The generated code uses many types from com.querydsl.core.


After making all those changes, running ./mvnw compile succeeds and the expected sources are generated. But there are still problems with executing javafx:run. You have the wrong module name in your POM; it should be:
<mainClass>
    com.intelidia.testquerydsl/com.intelidia.testquerydsl.testquerydsl.HelloApplication
</mainClass>

And you need to add two more directives to your module-info.java file:
exports com.intelidia.testquerydsl.testquerydsl to javafx.graphics;
opens com.intelidia.testquerydsl.testquerydsl to javafx.fxml;

And finally, executing ./mvnw compile javafx:run should work.

Full Code
Here is the new module-info.java:
module com.intelidia.testquerydsl {
    requires static java.compiler;
    requires com.querydsl.core;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;


    exports com.intelidia.testquerydsl.testquerydsl to 
            javafx.graphics;

    opens com.intelidia.testquerydsl.testquerydsl to 
            javafx.fxml;
}

And the new pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.intelidia.testquerydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestQuerydsl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TestQuerydsl</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>

        <javafx.version>17.0.6</javafx.version>
        <javax.persistence.version>2.2</javax.persistence.version>
        <querydsl.version>5.1.0</querydsl.version>
        <junit.version>5.10.0</junit.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.persistence.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
                            <version>${javax.persistence.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <annotationProcessors>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </annotationProcessors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>
                                com.intelidia.testquerydsl/com.intelidia.testquerydsl.testquerydsl.HelloApplication
                            </mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

 

works flawlessly, thanks for the time you took to investigate this, the answer you provided and the explanations!
